# How to display entities in tweet

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, twitter, tweepy

In order to lower the number of calls to Twitter API we are caching some tweets on the server and displaying them directly from there. The problem is that when we display them the entities - link, hashtags and twitter users are not active links.

Is there a way to make them links both front-end and back-end solutions are acceptable. We are using Python/TweePy for the back-end and jQuery for the front.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the links are not active'? Are they not rendered as clickable links on the webpage, or do they not point to the correct page?